# Placing 2 different tikz plots side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two different tikz plots as .tex file , how to place them side by side ? These were made by @hpekristiansen ([How to draw a custom function on tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/672466/how-to-draw-a-custom-function-on-tikz/672478?noredirect=1#comment1671154_672478))

**Plot 1: (right)**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, calc, arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
state/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=0.8cm, inner sep=0pt},
arrow/.style={-Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
dot/.style={minimum size=4pt, inner sep=0pt, rounded corners=1pt, fill},
node distance=0.1cm and 2cm,
]
\node[state] (y1) {$y_1$};
\node[state, below=of y1] (y2) {$y_2$};
\node[state, below=0.8cm of y2] (yn) {$y_n$};
\node[state, below=of yn] (b) {$b$};
\node[state, above right=of y1] (a11) {$a_{11}$};
\node[state, below=of a11] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
\node[state, below right=of yn] (an1) {$a_{n1}$};
\node[state, below=of an1] (b1) {$b_1$};
\node[state, right=of a11] (ak1) {$a_{k1}$};
\node[state, right=of a21] (ak2) {$a_{k2}$};
\node[state, right=of an1] (ann) {$a_{nn}$};
\node[state, right=of b1] (bn) {$b_n$};
\node[state] at ($(ak2)!0.5!(ann)+(2,0)$) (sigma) {$\Sigma$};
\node[dot] at ($(a21)!0.3!(an1)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($(a21)!0.5!(an1)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($(a21)!0.7!(an1)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($(ak2)!0.3!(ann)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($(ak2)!0.5!(ann)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($(ak2)!0.7!(ann)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($($(a21)!0.5!(ak2)$)!0.3!($(an1)!0.5!(ann)$)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($($(a21)!0.5!(ak2)$)!0.5!($(an1)!0.5!(ann)$)$) {};
\node[dot] at ($($(a21)!0.5!(ak2)$)!0.7!($(an1)!0.5!(ann)$)$) {};
\node[dot] (dot1) at ($(a11)!0.5!(ak1)$) {};
\node[dot] (dot2) at ($(b1)!0.5!(bn)$) {};
\draw[arrow] (a11) -- (dot1) edge (ak1);
\draw[arrow] (b1) -- (dot2) edge (bn);
\draw[arrow] (y1) --node[above, font=\small]{$w_{11}^1$} (a11);
\draw[arrow] (y1) -- (a21);
\draw[arrow] (y2) --node[above, font=\small]{$w_{11}^1$} (a21);
\draw[arrow] (y2) -- (a21);
\draw[arrow] (y2) -- (an1);
\draw[arrow] (yn) -- (a11);
\draw[arrow] (yn) --node[above, font=\small]{$w_{11}^1$} (an1);
\draw[arrow] (yn) --node[above, font=\small]{$w_{n1}^1$} (b1);
\draw[arrow] (b) -- (a11);
\draw[arrow] (b) -- (an1);
\draw[arrow] (b) -- (b1);
\draw[arrow] (ak1) -- (sigma);
\draw[arrow] (ak2) -- (sigma);
\draw[arrow] (ann) -- (sigma);
\draw[arrow] (bn) -- (sigma);
\draw[arrow] (sigma) -- +(1,0)node[right]{$I$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Plot 2: (left)**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{>=latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={f(\x)=sin((\x-2)^2 r)+2;},
]
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain={0.5:7}, samples=50, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)});
\draw[blue!50!black, densely dotted] (0,2) -- (7,2);
\draw[densely dashed] (2.0,0) node[below]{$x_1$} -- +(0,{f(2.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_1$};
\draw[densely dashed] (2.5,0) node[below]{$x_2$} -- +(0,{f(2.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_2$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.0,0) node[below]{$x_3$} -- +(0,{f(3.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_3$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.5,0) node[below]{$x_4$} -- +(0,{f(3.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_4$};
\draw[densely dashed] (5.0,0) node[below]{$x_n$} -- +(0,{f(5.0)}) node[above right]{$y_n$};
\draw[thick, <->] (0,6) --node[above, rotate=90, font=\bfseries] (Y) {$f(x)$} (0,0) -- (7,0) node[below, font=\bfseries] {Quad. points};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I made both these pictures. When using other peoples work, you should site the source. -put links to your previous questions.

Comment: @hpekristiansen sure, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hm, what about `<tikzpicture left> \qquad <tikzpicture right>` ?

Complete MWE (Minimal Working Wxample), where I took liberty and pictures code by use of `chains`,  `scope` and `quotes` make a wee bit shorter. Since left picture bit is quite wide, I reduced its width by defining `x=8mm` and wrote abscisa name in two lines.

**Edit:**

- You not provide any information about your document layout, so in MWE below is used it default setting of `article` document class
- To see, so far not mentioned issues of your desired figure, now is added:

```
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
```

which indicate (upper part of) page layout.

- Regardless, that left picture is narrowed for about 20% both images still spill out of text area on page. That between them are still some distance in example below is used `\qquad` for determining between them.
- compilation of this MWE, as you can notice in your test, throw warnings

```
Overfull \hbox (102.33492pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 16--89
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, chains,
                positioning, 
                quotes}  % added

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8cm,
declare function={f(\x)=sin((\x-2)^2 r)+2;},
                    ]
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain={0.5:7}, samples=50, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)});
\draw[blue!50!black, densely dotted] (0,2) -- (7,2);
\draw[densely dashed] (2.0,0) node[below]{$x_1$} -- ++ (0,{f(2.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_1$};
\draw[densely dashed] (2.5,0) node[below]{$x_2$} -- ++(0,{f(2.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_2$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.0,0) node[below]{$x_3$} -- ++(0,{f(3.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_3$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.5,0) node[below]{$x_4$} -- ++(0,{f(3.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_4$};
\draw[densely dashed] (5.0,0) node[below]{$x_n$} -- ++(0,{f(5.0)}) node[above right]{$y_n$};
\draw[thick, <->] (0,4) -- node[above, rotate=90, font=\bfseries] (Y) {$f(x)$} (0,0) 
                        -- (7,0) node[below left, align=center, font=\bfseries] {Quad.\\ points};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\qquad% distance between tikzpictures
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 17mm,
  start chain = going below,
 state/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt},
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
   dot/.style = {rounded corners=1pt, inner sep=2pt, fill},
       every edge/.append style = {arr},    % added
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, pos=0.4, sloped}, % added
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, on chain}] % added
\node   (y1) {$y_1$};
\node   (y2) {$y_2$};
\node[below=8mm of y2] (yn) {$y_n$};
\node   (b) {$b$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state}]           % added
\node[above right=of y1] (a11) {$a_{11}$};
\node[above right=of y2] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
\node[below right=of yn] (an1) {$a_{n1}$};
\node[below right=of b]  (b1)  {$b_1$};

\node[right=of a11] (ak1) {$a_{k1}$};
\node[right=of a21] (ak2) {$a_{k2}$};
\node[right=of an1] (ann) {$a_{nn}$};
\node[right=of b1]  (bn)  {$b_n$};
\node[right=of {$(ak2)!0.5!(ann)$}] (sigma) {$\Sigma$};
    \end{scope}
    
\path   ($(a21)!0.3!(an1)$) node (d11) [dot] {}  
        ($(a21)!0.5!(an1)$) node (d12) [dot] {} 
        ($(a21)!0.7!(an1)$) node (d13) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(ak2)!0.3!(ann)$) node (d31) [dot] {}
        ($(ak2)!0.5!(ann)$) node (d32) [dot] {}
        ($(ak2)!0.7!(ann)$) node (d33) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(d11)!0.5!(d31)$) node (d31) [dot] {}
        ($(d12)!0.5!(d32)$) node (d32) [dot] {}
        ($(d13)!0.5!(d33)$) node (d33) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(a11)!0.5!(ak1)$) node (d20) [dot] {} 
        ($(b1)!0.5!(bn)$)   node (d24) [dot] {}; % changed
        
\path   (a11) edge (d20) edge (ak1)
        (b1)  edge (d24) edge (bn);              % changed
        
\draw   (y1) edge ["$w_{11}^1$"] (a11)           % changed, used `quotes` library
        (y1) edge (a21)
        (y2) edge ["$w_{21}^1$"] (a21) 
        (y2) edge (an1)
        
        (yn) edge (a11) 
        (yn) edge ["$w_{11}^1$"] (an1)
        (yn) edge ["$w_{n1}^1$"] (b1);
        
\foreach \i in {a11, an1, b1}
    \draw[arr] (b) -- (\i);       % changed, used loops
\foreach \i in {ak1, ak2, ann, bn}
    \draw[arr] (\i) -- (sigma);   % changed, used loops
\draw[arr] (sigma) -- +(1,0) node[right]{$I$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Addendum:**
From your comments below follows:

- that you like to have bigger distance between pictures
- from above figure follows, that this is possible without aforementioned warnings only in two cases:

  - when you change (so far unknow) page layout, as is done in the MWE below, by use of the `geometry` package, or
  - locally change `\textwidth` for the figure only by use for example `changepage` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
% second case
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}  % added
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}  % added

\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth} % defined in changepage package
% left image
\hfill  % <--- make maximal possible distance between pictures
% right image
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

which after two compilations gives:

[image]

- Regarding to desired interchange of `tikzpicture` position, when you change page layout for example so, that page borders widths are 25mm, see the next MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document

\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % < added
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains,
                positioning,
                quotes}  % added

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.8cm,
declare function={f(\x)=sin((\x-2)^2 r)+2;},
                    ]
\draw[blue!50!black] plot[domain={0.5:7}, samples=50, smooth] (\x,{f(\x)});
\draw[blue!50!black, densely dotted] (0,2) -- (7,2);
\draw[densely dashed] (2.0,0) node[below]{$x_1$} -- ++ (0,{f(2.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_1$};
\draw[densely dashed] (2.5,0) node[below]{$x_2$} -- ++(0,{f(2.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_2$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.0,0) node[below]{$x_3$} -- ++(0,{f(3.0)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_3$};
\draw[densely dashed] (3.5,0) node[below]{$x_4$} -- ++(0,{f(3.5)}) node[above=4pt]{$y_4$};
\draw[densely dashed] (5.0,0) node[below]{$x_n$} -- ++(0,{f(5.0)}) node[above right]{$y_n$};
\draw[thick, <->] (0,4) -- node[above, rotate=90, font=\bfseries] (Y) {$f(x)$} (0,0)
                        -- (7,0) node[below left, align=center, font=\bfseries] {Quad.\\ points};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\hfill  % <--- make maximal possible distance between pictures
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 3mm and 15mm,
  start chain = going below,
 state/.style = {circle, draw, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt},
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
   dot/.style = {rounded corners=1pt, inner sep=2pt, fill},
       every edge/.append style = {arr},    % added
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize, pos=0.4, sloped}, % added
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state, on chain}] % added
\node   (y1) {$y_1$};
\node   (y2) {$y_2$};
\node[below=8mm of y2] (yn) {$y_n$};
\node   (b) {$b$};
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[nodes={state}]           % added
\node[above right=of y1] (a11) {$a_{11}$};
\node[above right=of y2] (a21) {$a_{21}$};
\node[below right=of yn] (an1) {$a_{n1}$};
\node[below right=of b]  (b1)  {$b_1$};

\node[right=of a11] (ak1) {$a_{k1}$};
\node[right=of a21] (ak2) {$a_{k2}$};
\node[right=of an1] (ann) {$a_{nn}$};
\node[right=of b1]  (bn)  {$b_n$};
\node[right=of {$(ak2)!0.5!(ann)$}] (sigma) {$\Sigma$};
    \end{scope}

\path   ($(a21)!0.3!(an1)$) node (d11) [dot] {}
        ($(a21)!0.5!(an1)$) node (d12) [dot] {}
        ($(a21)!0.7!(an1)$) node (d13) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(ak2)!0.3!(ann)$) node (d31) [dot] {}
        ($(ak2)!0.5!(ann)$) node (d32) [dot] {}
        ($(ak2)!0.7!(ann)$) node (d33) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(d11)!0.5!(d31)$) node (d31) [dot] {}
        ($(d12)!0.5!(d32)$) node (d32) [dot] {}
        ($(d13)!0.5!(d33)$) node (d33) [dot] {}; % changed
\path   ($(a11)!0.5!(ak1)$) node (d20) [dot] {}
        ($(b1)!0.5!(bn)$)   node (d24) [dot] {}; % changed

\path   (a11) edge (d20) edge (ak1)
        (b1)  edge (d24) edge (bn);              % changed

\draw   (y1) edge ["$w_{11}^1$"] (a11)           % changed, used `quotes` library
        (y1) edge (a21)
        (y2) edge ["$w_{21}^1$"] (a21)
        (y2) edge (an1)

        (yn) edge (a11)
        (yn) edge ["$w_{11}^1$"] (an1)
        (yn) edge ["$w_{n1}^1$"] (b1);

\foreach \i in {a11, an1, b1}
    \draw[arr] (b) -- (\i);       % changed, used loops
\foreach \i in {ak1, ak2, ann, bn}
    \draw[arr] (\i) -- (sigma);   % changed, used loops
\draw[arr] (sigma) -- +(1,0) node[right]{$I$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{In this example is assumed, that both pictures are in \texttt{figure} float with this caption.}
    \end{figure}
\lipsum[66]
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I strongly encourage you to read some LaTeX introductory text, like [The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) and at least first tutorial and part Part III "TikZ ist kein Zeichenprogramm" in the Ti*k*Z package documentation.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Actually, how to add some space in between these two plots. They look quite close to each other.

Comment: Also, may you kindly tell me; what changes I would need to swap the left figure with the right. Such that right becomes left and left becomes right.

Comment: @Formal_this: in question you require showed order of image. Answer shows, how to insert images, so this should not be a problem interchange their appearing. For increasing distance: replace `\qquad` with `\hfill`.

Comment: @Formal_this Just the same as if you type `A\qquad B` you get A first, B second. To swap the order, do `B\qquad A`. There isn't really any difference with tikzpictures :)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Oh I actually tried that, but it showed the right plot at the top and left plot below (at the bottom) ; rather than getting it on the right side.

Comment: @Formal_this Did you by any chance have an empty line between the two? That would place the second one in a new paragraph, and hence on the next line. Just the same as if you had `A <empty line> B`, the B is at the start of a new paragraph :)

Comment: @Formal_this, see edited answer and added addendum. Hopefully now is answered all questions in your comments.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks a lot for the help. Yeah.